# How to get the idle state of the application in IOS & android?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, android-activity

In my application,I have Activity A & B.In Activity B i want check the idle state of the application,if user didn't interact or minimize the application for few minutes means how to revert it back to Activity A.I don't know how to find out the Idle time of the application.Can any one know help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in iOS:

1) `Create a new file -> Objective-C class -> type in a name (in my case TIMERUIApplication) and change the subclass to UIApplication. You may have to manually type this in the subclass field. You should now have the appropriate .h and .m files.`

2) in .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//the length of time before your application "times out". This number actually represents seconds, so we'll have to multiple it by 60 in the .m file
#define kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes 5
#define kMaxIdleTimeSeconds 60.0

//the notification your AppDelegate needs to watch for in order to know that it has indeed "timed out"
#define kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification @"AppTimeOut"

@interface TIMERUIApplication : UIApplication
{
    NSTimer     *myidleTimer;
}

-(void)resetIdleTimer;

@end
```

3) .m file

```
#import "TIMERUIApplication.h"

@implementation TIMERUIApplication

//here we are listening for any touch. If the screen receives touch, the timer is reset
-(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super sendEvent:event];

    if (!myidleTimer)
    {
        [self resetIdleTimer];
    }

    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    if ([allTouches count] > 0)
    {
        UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
        if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan)
        {
            [self resetIdleTimer];
        }

    }
}
//as labeled...reset the timer
-(void)resetIdleTimer
{
    if (myidleTimer)
    {
        [myidleTimer invalidate];
    }
    //convert the wait period into minutes rather than seconds
    int timeout = kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes * 60;
    myidleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeout target:self selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
//if the timer reaches the limit as defined in kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes, post this notification
-(void)idleTimerExceeded
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification object:nil];
}


@end
```

4) in the main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TIMERUIApplication.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([TIMERUIApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

5) in appdelegate

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TIMERUIApplication.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{      
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidTimeout:) name:kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification object:nil];

    return YES;
}

-(void)applicationDidTimeout:(NSNotification *) notif
{
    //revert to Activity A
}
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

Are your question about iOS or Android?

On iOS, in your AppDelegate you have methods that are called on your application will enter in background and foreground, you can store the timestamp of each moment and calc the time.

Also, you have the applicationState (check UIApplication documentation), using this property you can know if your application is running active, background or inactive.

The setIdleTimerDisabled method that Sunny answered is used to active/deactivate the timer that turns screen off when you stay some secs/mins without any touch on the screen. It's very common to be used by Flashlight applications or games played with accelerometer.

I don't know about Android.